# How to read an slice of like []interface{} in Go?

Tags: go

I have something like this:

```
a := []interface{}{}
b := []interface{}{}
type S struct {
  text string
}


s := S{"string"}
t := S{"string"}
a = append(a, s)
b = append(b, t)
a := append(a, b)

a
```

And now I want to read elements of a, or elements of elements.. but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called a type assertion. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

The simple example on that page is:

```
var x interface{} = 7  // x has dynamic type int and value 7
i := x.(int)           // i has type int and value 7`
```

The other thing to note is that a type assertion returns a value called `ok` that is true if the assertion is successful. Here's a simple code example for your case:

```
a := []interface{}{}
b := []interface{}{}
type S struct {
  text string
}


s := S{"string"}
t := S{"string"}
a = append(a, s)
b = append(b, t)
a = append(a, b)

assertedS,ok := a[0].(S)
if !ok { // If this is, in fact, not a value of type S, something is wrong
    // error handling
}

fmt.Println(assertedS) // Should show you the same thing as printing s

assertedB,ok := a[1].([]interface{})
if !ok {
    //...
}

assertedT,ok := assertedB[0].(S)
if !ok {
    //...
}

fmt.Println(assertedT) // Should show you the same thing as printing t
```

If you don't know ahead of time which list element is what, you can iterate through it and use the "type switch". http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements

```
switch x.(type) {
    // cases
}
```

Which allows you to perform conditional behavior based on what type the stored interface{} really is.

For instance, you might use

```
func ExtractSlice(a []interface{}) {
  for _,x := range a {
    switch i := x.(type) {
    case S:
        fmt.Println(i)
    case []interface{}:
        ExtractSlice(i) // Recursively unpacks b once it's found within a
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
a := []interface{}{}
b := []interface{}{}
type S struct {
    text string
}
s := S{"string"}
t := S{"string"}
a = append(a, s)
b = append(b, t)
a = append(a, b)
for _, v := range a {
    switch v.(type) {
    case S:
        fmt.Println("S", v)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Slice", v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This code example](http://play.golang.org/p/aXe_gjbBSJ) may help:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []interface{}{}
    b := []interface{}{}
    type S struct {
        text string
    }

    s := S{"string s"}
    t := S{"string t"}
    a = append(a, s)
    b = append(b, t)
    a = append(a, b)

    for _, v := range a {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

but be aware that you've defined `a` and `b` as slices of interfaces. This means, that when you do `a = append(a, b)` you're putting the `b` slice after the existing `a` string in the `a` slice, and therefore when you `range` over `a` you get:

> {string s} //interface of string
>   [{string t}] //slice of interface of string

Comment: This is about elements of a slice. How about **elements of elements** then. I'm guessing we need `reflect` to do that, but I don't know how?